# better way to code recursive if statements

Tags: javascript

I find myself in this position occasionally, and I'm sure there is a better way to do it than I am currently.

In this example, I'm trying to sort a group of times where I have conflicting items. I need to know what times are high-priority,can't be moved, vs low priority, can be moved. 
But I'm pretty sure this code is very inefficient.

```
var holdLowPriorities = [];

for (conflict = 0; conflict < sortedTimes.length - 1; conflict++) {
    var firstConflictTimeStart = sortedTimes[conflict][0];
    var firstConflictTimeEnd = sortedTimes[conflict][1];
    var secondConflictTimeStart = sortedTimes[conflict + 1][0];
    var secondConflictTimeEnd = sortedTimes[conflict + 1][1];

    if (firstConflictTimeStart < secondConflictTimeEnd && 
            firstConflictTimeEnd > secondConflictTimeStart) {
        // are either of the conflicts a high priority
        var firstContactPriority = sortedTimes[conflict][2];
        var secondContactPriority = ortedTimes[conflict + 1][2]

        if (firstConflictPriority == 2) {
            //this is high priority, can't move
        }
        if (secondConflictPriority == 2) {
            // this is also a priority, but has to move
        }
        // are either of the conflicts a low priority?
        if (firstConflictPriority == 0) {
            // this is a low priority so I can adjust the time
        } else if (secondConflictPriority == 0) {
            // this is a low priority so I can adjust the time
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't even know what to call this type of a problem, and therefore don't know what to look for, though I'm sure the answer isn't overly complicated (I hope not anyway).

Comment: you could make code easier to read (and quite possibly more efficient) by using some intermediate variables with accurate names

Comment: What is the structure of `sortedTimes` ?

Comment: Wow, that's one hard to maintain block of code... 10/10 for wanting to improve it... You definitely want to heed Mitch Wheat's advice - and once you've got the intermediate variables, edit your Q with the updated code.

Comment: Just for the record: there's no such thing as a "recursive 'if' statement"

Comment: Also: tabs don't work so well in Stackoverflow markdown - make sure you convert your code to space indentation.

Comment: @Pointy True :D but at least say it should be "nested"...

Comment: @Basiclife I would say that "nested" is the proper term if I had any confidence that I understood what this question is about.

Comment: @Pointy again - good point. I'm hoping intermediate variables will make it far more comprehensible...

Comment: That last else if is so lonely :(

Comment: sorry for the first post, I've updated the code. I know it is ugly, but hopefully less so now. As noted in the question, I wasn't sure what to even call this mess

Comment: @pedalpete I've put the code trough jsbeautifier.com and also added a couple of empty lines in order to make the code a bit more readable. Consider using shorter variable names - for instance: `timeA1`, `timeA2`, `timeB1`, `timeB2` ... also `i` instead of `conflict`

Comment: @pedalpete Also, you probably want to declare the `conflict` variable... And consider placing all those variable declarations at the top of the code, so that you don't have to read trough the whole code in order to figure out which variable names are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**switch**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement might help clean up your code a bit.

Comment: Then he would have to write multiple switch statements, because for some reason he has multiple variables in his if statements.  Plus he would only be limited to string values not conditions.

Comment: That's not the case in javascript, switch statements take expressions as well. (see the link)

Comment: he could probably even right it in one switch statement if he wrote a clever enough expression. =)

Comment: the switch statement definitely made the code more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:* you've altered the question so most of this becomes irrelevant.

Here is a simple clarification of it.

```
var holdLowPriorities = [];

for(conflict=0; conflict<sortedTimes.length-1; conflict++){
  var conflictTime = sortedTimes[conflict],
      nextConflictTime = sortedTimes[conflict + 1];
  if (conflictTime[0] >= nextConflictTime[1] || conflictTime[1] <= nextConflictTime[0]) {
    continue;
  }

  // are either of the conflicts a high priority 
  if (data[conflictTime[2]].stepsArr[conflictTime[3]].priority==2) {
    alert(data[conflictTime[2]].stepsArr[conflictTime[3]].
  }
  if (data[nextConflictTime[2]].stepsArr[nextConflictTime[3]].priority == 2) {
    alert(data[nextConflictTime[2]].stepsArr[nextConflictTime[3]].
  }  

  // are either of the conflicts a low priority?
  if (data[conflictTime[2]].stepsArr[conflictTime[3]].priority==0) {
    holdLowPriorities.push([conflictTime[2], conflictTime[3], conflict]);
  } else if (data[nextConflictTime[2]].stepsArr[nextConflictTime[3]].priority == 0) {
    holdLowPriorities.push([nextConflictTime[2], nextConflictTime[3], conflict+1])
  }

  //alert(data[nextConflictTime[2]].stepsArr[nextConflictTime[3]].prerequisite+' '+conflictTime[0]+' '+conflictTime[1]+' '+nextConflictTime[0]+' '+nextConflictTime[1]+' '+data[nextConflictTime[2]].stepsArr[nextConflictTime[3]].taskid+' / '+data[conflictTime[2]].stepsArr[conflictTime[3]].taskid);
}
```

Then this can be made more obvious by using a helper method and a couple more variables.

```
function conflictData(conflict) {
    return data[conflict[2]].stepsArr[conflict[3];
}

var holdLowPriorities = [];

for(conflict=0; conflict<sortedTimes.length-1; conflict++){
  var conflictTime = sortedTimes[conflict],
      nextConflictTime = sortedTimes[conflict + 1];
  if (conflictTime[0] >= nextConflictTime[1] || conflictTime[1] <= nextConflictTime[0]) {
    continue;
  }

  var thisConflictData = conflictData(conflictTime),
      nextConflictData = conflictData(nextConflictTime);

  // are either of the conflicts a high priority
  if (thisConflictData.priority == 2) {
    alert(thisConflictData);
  }
  if (nextConflictData.priority == 2) {
    alert(nextConflictData);
  }

  // are either of the conflicts a low priority?
  if (thisConflictData.priority == 0) {
    holdLowPriorities.push([conflictTime[2], conflictTime[3], conflict]);
  } else if (nextConflictData.priority == 0) {
    holdLowPriorities.push([nextConflictTime[2], nextConflictTime[3], conflict+1])
  }

  //alert(nextConflictData.prerequisite + ' ' + conflictTime[0] + ' ' + conflictTime[1] + ' ' + nextConflictTime[0] + ' ' + nextConflictTime[1] + ' ' + nextConflictData.taskid + ' / ' + thisConflictData.taskid);
}
```

When expressed like this, I think you can start to see probable bugs; high priority has conflictTime and nextConflictTime checks as if, if, whereas low priority has if, else if. Is this what is desired? You may be able to then put this/next conflict priority in a switch or reorganise the code more.  But I think it's now at the stage where it can be understood more readily.

Comment: thanks Chris, i'm finding it very interesting that most of the recommendations are about code readability rather than a different way to write the code, a function I wasn't aware of (other than switch) or something like that. Maybe I'm not as bad a programmer as I thought, just verbose with ugly code.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of data structures, there is nothing inherently inefficiently with if..else blocks. Even nested if..else are not a problem. In terms of readability it's another matter altogether. As a rule of thumb, large and deeply nested if..else blocks are hard to follow (for a human, computers of course have no problems with them).

First of all, I'd go with Mitch's suggestion to use intermediate variables to reduce code verbosity. In terms of efficiency it is definitely less memory efficient (though for javascript, it could potentially speed up access depending on the browser). But efficiency is not the point, code clarity is.

Secondly, use array literal syntax instead of `new Array()` : `holdLowPriorities.push([...])`. Again, less noise on the screen, the easier it is to see what's going on.

Third, there are several places where all you're doing is checking the priority of something. Use either a helper function or a method to simplify the code here: `checkProirity(sortedTimes,conflict,2)` or `sortedTimes.checkProirity(conflict,2)`. Again, a function/method call is inherently less efficient but the point is to improve code clarity for good readability.

Comment: Thanks Slebetman,I had actually changed the code while you were posting. I removed the 'new Array' stuff 'cause it isn't actually a part of this question. Using a helper function is one solution, but I am hoping that the correct answer is better than just getting another variable back from a helper function. But maybe that is the answer.